# Carrierwave+fog+s3 not working with Cloud Front URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, fog

I'm having this problem with `carrierwave+fog+s3` with Amazon `cloud front`. With the following setup I can upload files to s3 but after uploaded, the S3 Objects URLs I get from my rails app doesn't have the `assets_host` based URLs i.e I'm expeting the URLs to be looks like this format `https://mycloudfrontname.cloudfront.net/uploads/myfile.mp3`

But they all appear in this format `https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/myfile.mp3`

What might be wrong here?

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'XXXX',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'XXXX',
    :region                 => 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'mybucketname'
  config.asset_host     = 'https://mycloudfrontname.cloudfront.net'
  config.fog_public     = false
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

**UPDATE:**

I found this code bit from Carrierwave's `/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb` - So if we set the `asset_host` as on above code snippet this must work right? or is there any other configuration I must do as well?

```
def public_url
          if host = @uploader.asset_host
            if host.respond_to? :call
              "#{host.call(self)}/#{path}"
            else
              "#{host}/#{path}"
            end
          else
            # AWS/Google optimized for speed over correctness
            case @uploader.fog_credentials[:provider]
            when 'AWS'
              # if directory is a valid subdomain, use that style for access
              if @uploader.fog_directory.to_s =~ /^(?:[a-z]|\d(?!\d{0,2}(?:\d{1,3}){3}$))(?:[a-z0-9\.]|(?![\-])|\-(?![\.])){1,61}[a-z0-9]$/
                "https://#{@uploader.fog_directory}.s3.amazonaws.com/#{path}"
              else
                # directory is not a valid subdomain, so use path style for access
                "https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{@uploader.fog_directory}/#{path}"
              end
            when 'Google'
              "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/#{@uploader.fog_directory}/#{path}"
            else
              # avoid a get by just using local reference
              directory.files.new(:key => path).public_url
            end
          end
        end
```

Comment: Did you try the app config update?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. My config is about the same as yours. For some reason in my dev environment, I get URLs like ```http://assets/mycloudfrontname.cloudfront.net/uploads/myfile.mp3``` and it production, they're the ```s3``` urls.  BTW, you should not need ```#fog_directory``` if you have ```#asset_host```.  FWIW I also tried ```#fog_public = true```, to no avail. I spent about 5 hours on this today, researching online, poring over github and stepping through carrierwave code. I can't make heads or tails of any of it.

Answer (score 2):

Change `config.fog_public` to `true` and add `config.asset_host = 'YOUR_CND_ADDRESS'`. The `asset_host` doesn't work when `fog_public` is false

Answer (score 0):

In your environment file you need to set the asset host.  Just add the line below to your `config/environments/production.rb` file, and you should be okay.  Also may want to make sure you're using the latest version of carrierwave and fog gems.

```
-- config/environments/production.rb

Myapp::Application.configure do

  # Use Content Delivery Network for assets
  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://mycloudfrontname.cloudfront.net'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use asset_host.  The asset_host setting is for files served by the rails asset helpers.  CarrierWave files are handled in a different manner.  The config you are looking for is config.fog_host

```
config.fog_host = 'https://mycloudfrontname.cloudfront.net'
```

Comment: ```fog_host``` was renamed ```asset_host```. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/d7dba56ffe18a5ac5e49419ee9a9bf447c229c15/History.txt#L17